# How to prevent direct access to private members outside of getters/setters in the same class?

Tags: java, getter-setter, checkstyle

### Challenge

Given a class with a non-trivial getter and some other internal method accessing the same `private` member field:

#### Valid Example

```java
class TestType {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value == null || this.value.isEmpty() ? "default" : this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }

    public int getValueLength() {
        return this.getValue().length();
    }
}
```

I want to forbid the by-passing of the getter in the `getValueLength()` method.
The following implementation of `getValueLength()` should produce some kind of error (unit test failure, checkstyle error, or whatever else can be automated in a generic way):

#### Invalid Method

```java
    public int getValueLength() {
        // ERROR: possible NullPointerException
        return this.value.length();
    }
```

---

### Background

In my real-life code there is some lazy-loading going on inside the getter that only loads the actual value when it is being accessed for the first time. Calling `getValueLength()` first may result in a `NullPointerException` directly or perform wrong actions based on the missing value.

The motivation is to ensure that future developers don't forget to only use the getter method and never access the member directly. Since this is an isolated issue (i.e. only where this kind of lazy-loaded is being specifically added) it is acceptable if some extra annotations are required, e.g. on the member itself that it should only be accessed in selected methods and those methods to be marked as well -- or specific checkstyle comments enabling/disabling specific rules.

Comment: Why not initialize `value` to `"default"` instead of `null`? No more NPEs, and no more lazy init

Comment: Must it be in the same class? You could wrap `value` in a `LazyValue` class

Comment: You could always have an unintuitive name for `value` like `$value$` that'll make future developers look again before accessing it

Comment: The point of encapsulation is to hide implementation details from a utilizer of the class. That doesn't make much sense when you're hiding those details _from the implementaiton itself_, so I think OP's question was more "how do I ensure I don't accidentally use this field instead of my getter while making this class". For the sake of this, either removing the lazy init or wrapping in an object (to describe what it does approp.) would be best imo. Less a fan of obscure variable names.

Comment: (1) as per the "Background" part, initialising the value upfront would defeat the purpose of lazily loading a big chunk of data that is hardly used and in this particular example, the value may be set to `null` later on (2) wrapping into a `LazyValue` might be an option, but would prevent the getter and setter from being detected by our tools because of the different return type, (3) strange names would break with other existing rules and aren't that nice. The developer wouldn't know why the name is so weird.

Comment: I vote along (2), and you can chain up the getters from your `LazyValue` to return the appropriate type, fixing that problem. To make (1) work, you'd likely need a flag to denote it being loaded, and it just gets messier. I misread the question to that part

Comment: You mention “Hopefully there is some way to achieve it via some tool” in a comment below.  Would a [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io) based solution be acceptable?

Comment: @VGR that’s actually what I was hoping for, in order to avoid having to change the code itself. Hence the `checkstyle` tag on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to put this answer to form:

```
class LoadableVar<T> {

    private T val;
    private Supplier<T> loader;

    public LoadableVar(Supplier<? extends T> loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    public T get() {
        if (this.val == null) {
            //see: volatile and double-locking if multithreading
            this.val = this.loader.get();
        }
        return this.val;
    }

    public void set(T overwrite) { //WARN: ignores the loader!
        this.val = overwrite;
    }
}
```

Then, in applying it to your class:

```
class TestType {
    private final LoadableVar<String> value;

    public TestType() {
        //can also be passed into the class, or done however you desire
        this.value = new LoadableVar<>(() -> /* load string from i/o, etc */);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value.get();
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue) {
        this.value.set(newValue); //I don't think this should be settable, personally
    }

    public int getValueLength() {
        return this.getValue().length();
    }
}
```

Now when you are writing code within TestType's scope:

```
String s;
s = this.value; //compile error!
s = this.getValue(); //OK
s = this.value.get(); //OK
```

As you can see, in doing it this way you've also made `TestType#getValue` redundant, you could simply allow `value` to be a `protected` member (and in which case, I'd remove those setters and make it immutable).

Comment: In the `LoadableVar` class, one might want to wrap the `val` into an `Optional` or take some other measure to also allow for the loaded value to be `null` without executing the possibly resource-hungry `Supplier` repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enforce this in code.

However, since you mention in a comment, “Hopefully there is some way to achieve it via some tool,” and the question is tagged with [checkstyle](/questions/tagged/checkstyle), I believe you can create a custom rule:

```xml
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="id" value="valueField"/>
    <property name="format" value="\bvalue\b"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
    <property name="message" value="Do not use 'value' field directly;  use getValue() instead."/>
</module>
```

You would then want to suppress that check for your own “valid” lines:

```xml
<module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
    <property name="idFormat" value="valueField"/>
</module>
```

And in the code:

```
private String value;   // SUPPRESS CHECKSTYLE

public String getValue() {
    return this.value == null || this.value.isEmpty() ? "default" : this.value; // SUPPRESS CHECKSTYLE
}

public void setValue(String newValue) {
    this.value = newValue;  // SUPPRESS CHECKSTYLE
}
```

(There are other ways to suppress Checkstyle’s checks with comments, which you may find more visually pleasing.  See the [filters](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html) documentation.)

When actually running Checkstyle, you probably want to restrict it to that one source file.  For instance, if using Ant, you might do:

```xml
<taskdef resource="com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/ant/checkstyle-ant-task.properties"
     classpath="tools/checkstyle-8.33-all.jar"/>

<checkstyle config="checkstyle.xml">
    <fileset dir="src/main/java" includes="**/TestType.java"/>
</checkstyle>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input and effort. So that means I have to specifically formulate such a checkstyle rule for every occurrence of this pattern and execute it explicitly for the respective file. Sounds like a lot of work. I was hoping for a more generic solution. I guess if a particular naming convention is being followed for these things it might be feasible, but I’m leaning towards the `LazyValue` wrapper approach then.

Comment: Yeah, it is a lot of work.  My own preferred solution is simply to add javadoc to the private field that stresses no one should access it directly.  I expect developers to pay attention to any code element’s javadoc before using it.  But then, I’m sometimes an idealist.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to protect a member from its own class, however you can protect a member from its children/subclasses. For example:

```java
class TestParent {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value == null || this.value.isEmpty() ? "default" : this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }

}

class TestType extends TestParent {
    public int getValueLength() {
        return this.getValue().length();
    }
}
```

This way TestType can still use `setValue()` and `getValue()`, but trying to directly access `this.value` will not work because `value` has private access in `TestParent`

Comment: This can be a good answer for some cases, but keep in mind you'll run into roadblocks applying this logic to an `enum` or multiple inheritance (inherit to relate, not to access). Following @ChristianScott's comment, you could instead wrap the field in an object such that the only way to get it at all is through a getter.

Comment: Fair point for subtypes (that's why the member is already `private` in the question). Unfortunately that does not answer my question. Hopefully there is some way to achieve it via some tool.